# Usage of. comma

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

1) I bought a tie and a shirt and a hat.

2) I bought a tie, a shirt, and a hat.

Are both 1 and 2 correct?

Please let me know the difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [double and's in list and commas](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/551180/double-ands-in-list-and-commas)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean by "correct."  Neither is ungrammatical, but the first option is not generally correct under any standard of formal style.  There are some style guides in which the second is incorrect, while in others it is correct.

Comment: In other words, it's not usual to put _and_ before every item in a list of three or more. The second comma in (2) is an _Oxford comma_ https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma

Comment: @KateBunting indeed, it's not usual, but I have recently noticed that I am increasingly inclined to write "and" or "or" for each additional list item instead of using commas, in line with the first example.  It strikes me as perfectly fine in a colloquial style, and sometimes more appropriate than the formal-sounding list with commas.